# json returned from a jsonresult in asp.net mvc 

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, redirect, jsonresult

I am returning this from a json result from a controller,

```
 var genericResult = new { redirectUrl = Url.Action("Create", "Registration")
                                , isRedirect = true };
return Json(genericResult);
```

but when i inspect through firebug,

`{"redirectUrl":"/","isRedirect":true}`

```
       if (data.isRedirect) {
            window.location.href = json.redirectUrl;
        }
```

Any suggestion.... How to redirect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how it's been declared, either fix `data` to `json`, or fix `json` to `data`.

Comment: there is no value `{"redirectUrl":"/"`

Comment: Then you need to fix `json.redirectUrl` to `data.redirectUrl`.